# Can't make Elastic Beanstalk work with AWS Codeartifact

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codeartifact

So the problem is pretty simple - I've set up the IAM roles, created a prebuild hook, ensured that it runs, but when I try to log in to the AWS CodeArtifact during deployment it fails with an exit status 243 and no additional info whatsoever
Maybe someone encountered a similar problem and was able to solve it easier than having to use the AWS CLI to log in?